# C# XAML Metro Image dynamic Source

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I like to do simple animation using one Image control in XAML and swaping Source of `Image` to other in interval 1 second.

But when I do that, the image is flickering. I using this code (at `Tick` event handler of `Timer`):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ms-appx:/Sprites/Running/" + y++ + ".png", 
              UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
BitmapImage textureBitmap = new BitmapImage(uri);

this.ImageHolder.Source = textureBitmap;
```

Where can the problem be ? Should I cache BitmapImages?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to declare a [StoryBoard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in your xaml:

```
    <Storyboard>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:0" 
            Storyboard.TargetName="ImageHolder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" 
               Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Frame1Image}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" 
               Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Frame2Image}"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" 
               Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Frame3Image}"/>
            <!-- etc -->
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

So, you have to add sprites to static resources, and run a StoryBoard.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to do it without using Storyboard. Is there other way?

Comment: Try to preload images before starting the animation.

Comment: Is good way for preloading using `Dictionary<int, BitmapImage>` with instances, then accessing it by int index?