# C# XAML Metro Image dynamic Source - more sources

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml

I have previous question on [C# XAML Metro Image dynamic Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930661/c-sharp-xaml-metro-image-dynamic-source)

Everything is okey, but when I using 3 "buffers" and switching them, I see flickering.

```
public Dictionary<int, BitmapImage>[] SpritesBuffer = new Dictionary<int,BitmapImage>[3];

(...)

image.Source = SpritesBuffer[0][0]; //first time use

(...)

timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 16);
timer.Tick += SwitchImageSource;

timer.Start();
```

In SwitchImageSource() I using foreach to loop throught images from 1. buffer, on some action I switch buffer to 2. and looping throught images from buffer 2. etc.

But when I already looped throught buffer 1, 2 and 3 it`s everything okey and images doesnt flickering. But on first loop I see flickering.

I tried to switch source before showing image using:

```
foreach (Dictionary<int, BitmapImage> dic in SpritesBuffer)
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<int, BitmapImage> keyVal in dic)
                {
                    image.Source = keyVal.Value;
                }
           }
```

But it doesnt work.

How can I solve this problem please?
Thank you!